# How do I convert string to int for a custom array length when using string arrays and char arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

So i'm making a simple program that first tells the user that the user will be able to create an array that saves the names of cities. For that I would need a string array so you know I can use words for the city names. After telling the user this it was ask how many city names they would like to enter. This is where the main issue occurs. This would be creating the length of the array but I can't start a string array with an int length. Can't convert string[] to int[]. 
In the code this happens on line 16.
My second issue is at the end after they enter the city names it asks "are these names correct?" and if they say no it will go back the beginning. I tried to use a do statement here but I couldn't because it won't let me use the array later after the do statement since it was created in the do statement. I have no idea how to fix this/ any other way to do it. 
Finally here is the actual code so you can see where the issues are:

```
import java.util.*;
public class MCassignment27
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();
    String again;
    do
    {
    System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
    System.out.println("\nYou will be able to create an array that saves the names of cities");
    System.out.println("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
    System.out.println("\nHow many cities would you like to enter?");
    int numcities = k.nextInt();
    String savedcities[] = new int[numcities];
    String cities = "";
    for (int i = 0;i < savedcities.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
      System.out.print("\nPlease enter the name of city #" + (i+1) + ":");
      cities += savedcities[i];
      savedcities[i] = k.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
    System.out.println("\nYour list of cities:");
    for (int j = 0;j < savedcities.length; j++)
    {
     System.out.println((j+1) + ". " + savedcities[j]); 
    }
    System.out.println("Are these all the cities you wanted to enter? y/n");
    again = k.nextLine();
    }
    while (again.equals("y") );
    System.out.println("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
    int rand = r.nextInt(savedcities.length);
    String word = savedcities[rand];
    char arr[] = word.toCharArray();
    for(int u=0; u<savedcities.length; u++)
    {
      System.out.println("Data at [" + u + "] = " + savedcities[u]);
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to extend a thank you in advance and I appreciate your time even if you don't respond, I appreciate you read it. :) Have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing `String savedcities[] = new int[numcities];`

can be changed to `String savedcities[] = new String[numcities];`

When initializing arrays in Java you use the same type after the new keyword as the array you're looking to create

for example: `Object[] myObjArray = new Object[size]`
or `int[] myIntArray = new int[size]`

Second, change your while statement from `while (again.equals("y") );` to `while (again.equals("n") );` or `while (!again.equals("n") );`

the while statement continues the loop as long as the condition is true. In this case if the user types `y` the loop starts again. However, according to what you said the loop should only continue when the user types `n`

In which case, for clarity sake, maybe rename `again` to `done`

Also place the declaration of your array outside of the do while so it can be used outside the do while.

```
String[] savedcities;
do {
      .... your code...
      //when you initialize the array do it like the following
      savedCities = new String[numCities];
      for (int i = 0;i < savedcities.length; i++)
      {
         ...inside for loop....
      }
      ... rest of do while ....       
}
```

Now your last issue of it skipping the first city choosing phase is a bit tricky...
when the program reaches these lines:

```
System.out.println("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
System.out.print("\nPlease enter the name of city #" + (i+1) + ": ");
savedcities[i] = k.nextLine();
```

on the first pass there actually is a line to read. (You can determine this by printing the results of `k.hasNext()`)

That's because `k.nextInt()` read an integer from the console but left the breakspace character behind. That breakspace character was typed to the console when the user types the number and then hits enter.

so `k.nextLine()` reads that breakspace character and inputs into the first city spot. You can check this by running in debug mode as well.

There are a couple of ways to solve this. One hacky way that I used was to call `k.nextLine()` after calling `k.nextInt()`

That will effectively pull out the breakspace character.

Alternatively you can try to read the whole line and then parse the value into an integer:

`int numcities = Integer.parseInt(k.nextLine());`

The last section of your code loops over savedCities:

```
for(int u=0; u<savedcities.length; u++)
{
    System.out.println("Data at [" + u + "] = " + savedcities[u]);
}
```

but you already have `arr[]` which contains all the characters of the random city you chose. Loop over that instead.

Comment: While this seems to make the program run it does not run correctly. This may not have anything to do this string or int but I could like to ask you. When I run the program I input the amount of cities it skips the option to enter the name for city 1 (array element #0)

Comment: also when I change it to n (that did need to be changed thanks) but it didnt solve this issue of not being able to use the array variable later. the exact error is array savedcities cannot be resolved to a variable. This happens all times I use this variable after the while statement

Comment: you can declare it before the do and initialize it in the do.

Comment: That only leaves me with one more issue, and up until here I Really do thank you. My last issue is that tiny bit of code at the bottom where it says " System.out.println("Data at [" + u + "] = " + savedcities[u]); " It is supposed to spell out the random city it chose but instead it just says all the cities in a list

Comment: There that completely worked. You are a godsend my friend and I really appreciate the time you took to help me. Thank you very much.